# Ionic5 & Typescript - propper http request : Convert fetch Promise to Observeable?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic5

I am porting my Ionic3 app into Ionic5 and am currently adding my http requests. 
In Ionic3 I used angular/http but seems it was [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/http). 
This was my code with observables:

```
   this._http.get(requestURL)
      .map((result: Response) => {
        return this.run(result.json())
   });
```

Now, how do I get the same implementation done with Ionic5 that http is no more?

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch(url));
```

? 
The above seems to not work. `fromPromise does not exist on Rx.Observeable`.

Comment: What RxJS version are you using?

Comment: Just checked - 6.5.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with RxJS 6, you should use the [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) operator instead, which will convert the `promise` into an `observable`:

```
const request = fetch(url);

from(request).pipe(
  switchMap(response => response.json()),
 ... carry out other operations here.
)
```

Comment: where does `_http` come from?

Comment: @ElDude Sorry, I copied wrongly. It should be fetch instead

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that I had to replace the `map` function that is now gone with a `forEach`.

Comment: How would I convert the response to a object? I used to have `result.json()` as seen above. But It seems to fail for me right now. I am not sure how to handle the `Response` type.

Comment: @ElDude sorry for the late response. I have updated my answer to return `response.json()` in the rxjs pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, I meanwhile moved on to use `fetch` and promises instead. I could not get `switchMap` to work properly and see not much of benefit between either implementation. Thank you for the tips though.